# The Dangers of Joy

Tags: simchah-joy-happiness

We find in Chazal many times that joy and party can easily lead to sin. Most famously the Gemarah in Berachos 30b.

Why is this? Additionally, I recall learning that some sins are actually the products of sadness.

What's the depth behind this?

Comment: Note that the examples in Berachos 30B aren't talking about just joy, they're talking about _excessive_ joy. Rashi mentions that the excessive joy made it seem like he was 'kicking off the yoke' of Heaven. The forbidden joy would probably more commonly translated as something like 'levity' or ' frivolity' (often termed in Hebrew as 'Schok' or 'Kalus Rosh'.

Answer (score 3):

My personal guess (and on myself observed empirical experience) is that joy often leads to arrogance and lack of humility, especially if it is joy derived from the failures or wrongdoings of others. These feelings of 'superiority' tend to lead to sinful behaviours way more often than sadness. Sadness leaves me personally in a state of humility and at God's mercy.

In my opinion, true joy comes not from parties but from within. This kind of untainted joy shouldn't lead to sinful behaviours since it is true joy not derived from others.